# change the content in a sql-column on sql server directly

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

due to changes to the data model, the serialized xml of my classes are not valid anymore. Fortunately, it is enough to simply remove a xml-element to fix the old serialization.

I store those serialized objects (serialized as xml-text) in a sql-server 2008 database in a nvarchar(MAX) field. I am looking for the best way to automatically edit all xml to remove the bugging tag, without writing an application that fetches the data, removes the tag and writing the data back to the database.

Replacement could be done via RegEx, the following RegEx can extract the xml-element:

```
<list>.*</list>
```

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Comment: You should be able to do this by casting to XML and using XML methods to remove the tag I would have thought. Not an area I'm proficient in myself however!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a one-off, you could try a quick and dirty replace:

```
update  YourTable
set     col1 = substring(col1,1,charindex('<list>', col1)-1) +
              substring(col1,charindex('</list>', col1)+len('</list>'),len(col1))
where   charindex('<list>', col1) > 0
```

The `<` character is not allowed in XML, so you don't have to worry about text fields interfering.

Comment: Yeah, it's a one-off. That was exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!